# How do you finish working with a git project?

Tags: git

I'm new to git and github and I'm struggling to figure out what's going on with git in cmd. I've just made lots of commits and I'm done working on one of my repos (locally and pushed to GitHub).

I now want to work on another repo locally for which I have a repo on GitHub, but I'm not sure how to stop the connection between my local machine and GitHub for the repo I've just finished working on. Is there a way to break the connection in cmd between the local repo and the GitHub repo? A proper way to close it?

Subsequently, if I want to move to another project, how do I do this? Would I need to break the connection then start from scratch? i.e.:

```
# after breaking previous link start again with:
git init
git remote add origin URL
git push -u origin master
# make changes to files then:
git add .
git commit -m "message"
git push
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a way to break the connection in cmd between the local repo and the GitHub repo? A proper way to 'close' it?

You *can* break the connection between your local and the remote repository by using the `git remote remove` command, but you will not gain anything by doing that.

No, you do not need to "close" a repository if you don't work on it. You just stop working on it.

You can also just delete your local copy of the repository if you don't plan on working on it any further (assuming that you've pushed all relevant changes to the remote).

> Subsequently, if I want to move to another project, how do I do this? Would I need to break the connection then start from scratch?

You don't need to do anything if you don't break the connection between the local and the remote repository. Just continue working on the other project where you left it the last time.

Yes, if you start a *new* other project, you could use `git init` to create a new Git repository for it.

I'm assuming you are using separate directories for each project. Don't use the same directory for multiple unrelated projects with their own Git repositories.

Comment: hi @mkrieger1 I want to keep both projects, but just work on one after the other, so I don't want to delete the local repo. If I simply want to move from one project to the other is it simply a case of  `git remote remove` in the current directory then `cd`-ing into a new directory and doing the normal `git init` etc?

Comment: No, it's **just** `cd`-ing into a new directory (and if necessary `git init` there if it's a brand new project).

Comment: Ah ok, so if i `cd` into a project with an existing .git folder, i don't need to reinitialise (`git init`) it? I can simply just `cd` into it and move straight onto the `git remote add origin URL` bit?

Comment: Yes... and if you didn't remove the remote before, you can also skip that.

Answer (score 1):

As an addendum to [mkrieger1's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72374874/1256452)—and my addendum is too big and needs too much formatting to be a comment—let me say these things:

1. A *remote* is a short name you store in your local repository, such as `origin`.  Most Git repositories have no remote, or one remote named `origin`.
2. The function of this remote is mainly twofold:

   - It holds the URL for some other Git repository.
   - It acts as a prefix for *remote-tracking names* such as `origin/main`.

   A remote-tracking name is simply a way for your own Git repository to remember branch names found in some other Git repository.

The point of a remote-tracking name is simple: *commit hash IDs* are universal; all Git commits in every Git repository always have *different* hash IDs *unless* the two commits are literally exactly the *same commit*.  That is, whenever you make a new commit in *your* Git repository, your commit gets a new, totally-unique hash ID, never used before, never to be used again.<sup>1</sup>  That's true for every commit anyone ever makes.  But Git repositories do get together now and then and *share commits*, and when they do, the *shared* commits *share the hash IDs*.  In a very real sense, then, the hash ID *is* the commit, so if you have a commit with the right hash ID, you have the right commit.  If we (humans) worked with hash IDs, we wouldn't need branch names—but we don't work with hash IDs because they're *horrible*.

So, our repositories have branch names, which work OK with feeble human brains.  But a branch name stores *one* hash ID.  My repository branch name `xyzzy` can only store *my* latest xyzzy-branch commit.  If you and I are working together and using a second and/or third Git repository and want to call a commit `xyzzy` in some *shared* repository, I need *my own* `xyzzy`, you need *your own* `xyzzy`, and we can fiddle with a shared name as needed to synchronize our two separate repositories.

So, when I copy from your repo or from the shared repo, I don't want to call that commit `xyzzy`.  I want to use a *remote-tracking name* that remembers your `xyzzy` as `you/xyzzy`, or the shared repo's `xyzzy` as `origin/xyzzy`.  That way *my* `xyzzy` is *mine*.  I can mix and match whenever I want or need to.

To make remote-tracking names work, we need remote names.  So remote names provide the ability for us to have remote-tracking names, and now we're all fine!

Hence, having a remote `origin` in your Git repository simply gives you a way to reach out to some *other* Git repository.  You'll share *commits* with that other Git repository, and those will use the same raw hash IDs.  You'll *not* share *branch names* with that other Git repository—not exactly: they'll have *their* branch names, which you'll remember locally in your repo as remote-tracking names, and you'll have *your* branch names.  You'll use these to coördinate if and as needed.  (Depending on how you use GitHub or some other sharing site, you may never need it, but it's there if you do need it.)

#### Should you remove a remote?

You *can* run `git remote remove origin`, and your Git will remove the *name* origin.  This will remove the stored URL (part (a) of point 2 above) *and* the remote-tracking names (part (b) of point 2 above).  **It has no other effect.**  There is no active, ongoing connection between your repository and the other repository.  They only connect when *you say* your computer (your laptop or whatever) should *reach out to GitHub* (or whatever sharing site) and connect for as long as it takes to exchange some commits and/or update some remote-tracking names.  Then your computer and theirs disconnect.  There's no ongoing resource usage, other than the disk space used to hold the remote name and related data in your repository.<sup>2</sup>

So, in most cases, there's zero benefit from removing a remote.  It may get stale, but so what?  There's no carrying cost.

---

<sup>1</sup>The [pigeonhole principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_principle) tells us that this is mathematically impossible: some doomsday will eventually come when Git will stop working.  How many trillions of years that may be from now, perhaps after the heat death of the universe, is a function of the size of the hash ID and random chance and, absent deliberate malice, is not worth worrying about.  At least not until the [birthday problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem) rears its head, but never mind that.

<sup>2</sup>Due to "block sizes" on disk drives (512 bytes minimum, with 4k and larger being pretty common now where compatibility isn't required and going to 64K or 1MB or more as disk drive capacities swell past the 20 terabyte mark) and clever encoding, the space needed to hold the extra information is probably no bytes at all, as it probably fits in the existing block(s) in use.

Answer (score 0):

You simply initialise a new repo with  `git -init`
If you want to know how many repos in your folder run `git remote`
BR,

Comment: This in no way answers the question. Perhaps re-read the question to gain a better understanding of what the OP is asking.